# Simple code on swiping right and left to go back and fourth on a page using angular

Tags: angularjs, mobile

So I am working on a single page app and I am looking for a very simple code, if possible, to go back to a previous page while swiping. I have looked into many, but all seem to be very complex and very different.

All I want is to go back and fourth from a page by swiping. Nothing too complex really. Maybe using `ng-swipe-right` and `ng-swipe-left`? Also, this is an app for a garden center where they can look up some of their inventory.

Here is my index.html code:

```
<div class="main">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Here is my app.js code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[
    'ngRoute',
    'myApp.Home',
    'myApp.Search',
    'myApp.Inventory',
    'myApp.Sub',
    'myApp.Details'
]);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        }).
        when('/search', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/search/search.html',
            controller: 'SearchController'
        }).
        when('/inventory', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/inventory/inventory.html',
            controller: 'InventoryController'
        }).
        when('/coupons', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/coupons/coupons.html'
        }).
        when('/sales', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/sales/sales.html'
        }).
        when('/events', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/events/events.html'
        }).
        when('/locations', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/locations/locations.html'
        }).
        when('/subInventory/', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/subInventory/subInventory.html',
            controller: 'SubInventoryController'
        }).
        when('/detailsInventory/:productId', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/detailsInventory/detailsInventory.html',
            controller: 'DetailsInventoryController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## use ngSwipeLeft/Right

use the angualr directive `ng-swipe-left="expression"`

in your expression you can call a function bound to scope. This function can use the state function go.

```
$scope.goLeft = function(){state.go('someState')}
```

You will probebly need some params to define where you are in your app and what state to go to. or you could have this function on every state and hardcode the left and right states.

Comment: Have you ever used

'function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}'

Do you believe this could work well with ng-swipe-right?

Comment: never used it but it could messup if you can get to the state without the correct history